# Cordova (Phonegap) network Problems

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on an application, and it requires some data from my server, and i use

> navigator.onLine

to check if device is connected to internet or not, but it is returning false always.

Note : It was working fine with cordova version 5.4.0 i updated it to the latest 5.4.1 and now i am facing the problem.
I also have updated all the plugins.

Comment: thanks for down voting without any comment, it really helped me, it solved my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use cordova plugin to check network status,
Write below command to add network plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

write below code in js file :

```
document.addEventListener("online", function(){window.AppStatus = "online";}, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", function(){window.AppStatus = "offline";} , false);
```

Now you can check network status like :

```
     if(window.AppStatus == "online")
     {//your code}
```